# Создать программу, которая после ввода чисел с клавиатуры, выводила бы их в разных системах счисления (а именно в 8, 10, 16)

Tags: c++, visual-c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a = 5;
    float x = 2.78;
    printf("a=%o\n", a);
    printf("x=%o\n", x);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Вот код для 8-ричной системы счисления. На выходе получается непонятно что. В чем ошибка?

Comment: `%o`, как и `%x` предназначены для целых чисел. Как вывести число с плавающей точкой в 8-ричной или в 16-ричной системе счисления, можете посмотреть [тут](https://www.cyberforum.ru/cpp-beginners/thread2694541.html)

Comment: ничего не понятно, но спасибо) изучаю с++ относительно недавно. не могли бы Вы исправить ошибку в коде? или объяснить что должно получиться

Comment: Тут принципиально всё неправильно. Вам дали ссылку, там ответ

Comment: @ПавелЕриков Это будет вывод двоичного *представления*, а не в соответствующей системе счисления — типа, 32.45 вывести как 040.34631...

Comment: Не рассчитывайте так дешево отделаться :( — тут нужно писать программу перевода числа из одного представления в другое.

Comment: @Harry хмм, вы точно пролистнули ссылку до конца?

Comment: @ПавелЕриков Мне кажется, что да. В конце сплошняком работа с bitset. Если вы там нашли ответ — почему бы вам его просто не дать ответом?

Comment: @Harry ааагггааа, давно я с вами не общался конечно, уже и забыл ... В конце есть пример вывода в 8-ричной и в 16-ричной системе, правда не совсем то что нужно автору, но все же там это есть.

Comment: @ПавелЕриков Что-то того кода, который вы дали в ответе, я по вашей ссылке не увидел... Вы точно дали ту ссылку, которую надо? :)

Comment: @Harry ... "_правда не совсем то что нужно автору, но все же там это есть_"

Comment: @ПавелЕриков Просто покажите. Дайте ссылку на конкретный ответ. Просто мне уже интересно, что же я никак не увижу то, что вы говорите...

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример кода, который выводит число с плавающей точкой из 10-ричной с.с. в 8-ричную:

```
double number = 32.45f;
unsigned int decimal = number;        //Отделяем целую часть
number -= decimal;                    //Получаем дробную часть
int accuracy = 5;                     //Точность

std::printf("%o.", decimal);          //Выводим целую часть в 8-ричной с.с.
for (int i = 0; i < accuracy; ++i) {
    unsigned int tmp = (number *= 8); //Умножаем дробную часть на 8 и получаем целую часть
    cout << tmp;                      //Выводим целую часть
    number -= tmp;                    //Получаем дробную часть
}
```

Так же можно воспользоваться функцией `double modf(double x, double *iptr)`, которая разделяет число `x`, занося в `*iptr` целую и возвращая дробную часть.

Алгоритм точно такой же:

```
double number = 32.45f;
double decimal;
number = modf(number, &decimal);
int accuracy = 5;

std::printf("%o.", (unsigned int) decimal);

double tmp;
for (int i = 0; i < accuracy; ++i) {
    number *= 8;
    number = modf(number, &tmp);
    cout << (unsigned int)tmp;
}
```

Результат выполнения программы в обоих случаях одинаковый:

```
40.34631
```